# Dependency Injection - InvalidOperationException

Tags: c#

An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'Business.Abstract.IProductService' while attempting to activate 'WebApi1.Controllers.ProductsController'.
Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ActivatorUtilities.GetService(IServiceProvider sp, Type type, Type requiredBy, bool isDefaultParameterRequired)
here is my codes

```
using DataAccess.Concrete.EntityFramework;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;

namespace WebApi1
{
public class Startup
{

    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }
    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }
    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        //AOP
        //Autofac, Ninject,CastleWindsor, StructureMap, LightInject, DryInject -->IoC Container
        //AOP
        services.AddControllers();
        services.AddSingleton<IProductService, ProductManager>();
        services.AddSingleton<IProductDal, EfProductDal>();
        services.AddCors();
    }
    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseRouting();
        app.UseAuthorization();
        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllers();
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Does `ProductManager` implement `IProductService`?

Comment: If you want a better help, add `ProductManager` and `IProductService` code on the post

Comment: @Fildor would the code compile if it doesn't?

Comment: @Fildor i dont know if it would compile. But it would compile if ProductManager had no default or DI-able constructor, which is the problem that i suspect

Comment: @MichaelSchönbauer It actually shouldn't (at least it wouldn't with the DI framework we are using). But this is a very narrow window into the code and the comments also predict some surprises along the way ...

Comment: @Fildor thats true... but im curious. are you sure that this doesnt compile `Generic thing<TService, TImpl>` , how would you state as syntax that TImpl must implement TService in this case?

Comment: ok, found it : `public static Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.IServiceCollection AddTransient<TService,TImplementation> (this Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.IServiceCollection services) where TService : class where TImplementation : class, TService;`  -> it wouldnt compile youre right